# wxPython Image brightness control and changing between wximage, bitmap and PIL

Tags: bitmap, wxpython, python-imaging-library

I'm programming a gui and is looking for a method to control the brightness of my image using a slider. i've tried using ConvertToGreyscale but it is not giving what i want since images are in RGB and ConvertToGreyscale is in YUV.

i know that PIL have a lot of capabilities for images processing but i will have to convert between wximage, bitmap and PILimage. tried looking at http://wiki.wxpython.org/WorkingWithImages but solutions there doesn't seem to be working.

assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of trouble are you having with the examples provided in the link? "Not working" isn't much to go on.

Comment: i got the functions working. they are working. i'm just was using them the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change brightness you usually just need to multiply the pixel value by a constant. If the constant is less than 1.0 it will get darker, if it's greater it will get lighter. There are probably multiple ways of doing this with PIL but the first that comes to mind is the `Image.eval` function:

```
k = 1.5
out = Image.eval(in, lambda x: int(x * k))
```

[image]